# How to calculate middle of screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I came cross the following code and i don't know why center of screen are calculated by using screen width divided by height ?

```
class Gameplayscene: SKScene {

    var player:Player?

    var canMove=false
    var moveLeft=false

    var center:CGFloat?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        center = (self.scene?.size.width)! / (self.scene?.size.height)!

        print("the sence was loaded",center!)
    }
```

Comment: because it is wrong? what's your question?

Comment: Width divided by height is not the centre of the screen. It's the aspect ratio.

Comment: Because the variable was named terribly?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get **centre point** of the **main screen**, so just write down the code below,

```
let centerPointOfScreen = self.view.center
```

if your view is as **scene** so ,

```
let centerPointOfScreen = self.scene.center
```

Here, you get the centre point of the screen as `CGPoint(x:_, y:_)`

Answer (score 1):

`(self.scene?.size.width)! / (self.scene?.size.height)!` 
defines the aspect ratio of the screen and not the center of the screen.

Answer (score -2):

Calculation of centre is wrong. That'd give you the aspect ratio of the device say 4:3, 16:9, 16:10 and more. You would calculate the centre of screen as -

```
centerX = self.view.frame.size.width/2
 centerY = self.view.frame.size.height/2
 println("\(centerX) ,\(centerY)")
```

You would get the coordinates of the center in CGFloat.

Comment: Yes, thats what i thought. But in the video he said its calculate the center and it will use this value to compare where you click on screen. If position.x is greater than this center ,the sprite node (player) will move to right otherwise move to left. I am try to understand what is this center mean? he said this center is screen so i am confused.

Comment: Maybe you could check in the comments or community discussion to see if there are others who have pointed the same mistake out. It probably is a mistake on the tutor's part. What he meant was that you calculate the centre and (assume the screen is divided into two equal left and right halves according to the orientation) if user taps in right half then player will move right else move left.

Comment: self.view.frame.size.width compared to self.scene.size.width , what is the difference ? What is view.frame means?